# Efficiency problems with monitor connected to laptop

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm running 14.04 on a Dell Latitude. `lswh` reports my graphics card as "GF119M [NVS 4200M]". I have a monitor hooked up to it via a docking station. Lately I've been having performance problems with the graphics when the monitor is connected. It's as if the graphics is not updating properly. Often, I get a trail after the mouse pointer and the scrolling in my browser lags. Typically I see the previous screen and then it will take a second or two for it to update to the screen I ought to be seeing. Help appreciated.

`nvidia-settings --version` reports: version 340.29 (buildmeister@swio-cuda-x64-ubuntu1210-01)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: What GPU hardware are you using?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: I've added info about the GPU.

Comment: What's the output of `nvidia-setting --version`?

Comment: I've added the output of `nvidia-settings` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance about rolling forward and backward of driver versions after reading their page, leave a comment below.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. Fwiw, the xorg.edgers only made things worse. My computer crashed every now and then when using those drivers.

Comment: OK...  **:-(** Which version(s) did you try?  If possible ping me an the AU General Chat Room...

Comment: The only thing I tried was adding ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa and update the software. Having tried it for a couple of days I decided to remove it.

Comment: Ah, you should have done a `sudo apt-get install nvidia-349`....